# In-App Purchases taking too long in live version of the App

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, ios7

So we made our game, but contrary to what happens with our other games, this one is having problems with the IAPS, and we have no idea why. Sometimes it takes just a second with some purchases, but with others, it can just leave you hanging there for a couple of minutes. I have noticed mostly on my iPad 3, on an iPhone 5 only the Keep Playing purchase after failing a level takes time... https://itunes.apple.com/app/monster-pop-diary/id632332627?mt=8

Is anyone else having this problem ?